# Change Table td style using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have jquery append table. In that I was hiding initial row's column using CSS `style="display:none"` and after some event I want to display that Column.

```
my table id is-#148
tr id is -row1
```

I want to change that tr's first td style.
I referred lot of this but I didn't get proper solution.

Row is

```
 <tr  id="trid1"><td style="display:none"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="choose(2,<?php echo $loop->us_id;?>);"></td><td> <button class="btn btn-info btn-labeled fa fa-plus fa-lg" id="us_id" onclick="fun(<?php echo $loop->us_id;?>)" >Add Task</button></td></tr>
```

I want to change that CSS value using jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: Maybe `$('#trid1 td:eq(0)').show()`? Hiding/showing table cells is notoriously unreliable though. I'd avoid this if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#trid1 td:first-child").show();
```

This should probably work.

Comment: Yes. `:first-child` is optional in this case.

Comment: I added that `:first-child` in-case any more cells are added to the row.

Comment: Well... yes, for efficient mechanism, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
   //$('table').find('td').eq(0).show();

  // or

  //$('table').find('td:nth-child(1)').show();

  // or

  $('table').find('td:first-child').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vandolphreyes29/66uh0hz2/10/